# Formatting PHP explode array into HTML

Tags: php, html, explode, strpos

We have a client who wants to output cinema listings on their website. This particular cinema has provided us with a link to retrieve the information from. This link is simply outputted in plain text, with the elements seperated by ~|~

I am using explode and strpos to divide the listings into divs however it still isn't good enough for what I am wanting to achieve. I just can't get my head around what I can do to format this correctly. This is my code:

```
<?php

$theArray = explode("~|~", file_get_contents("THE URL"));

echo "<ul id=\"cinemaListings\">";

foreach($theArray as $item){

    $findcinemaid = '~77';
    $findcinemaname = 'Cinema Name';
    $findx = 'X';
    $findu = 'U';
    $findgen = 'Gen';
    $findlink = '.ie';

    if(strpos($item, $findcinemaname) !== false){

        echo "<div class='cinemaName'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(strpos($item, $findgen) !== false){

        echo "<div class='cinemaGen'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(strpos($item, $findcinemaid) !== false){

        echo "<li>";

    }elseif($item == $findx){

        echo "<div class='cinemaX'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(strlen($item) == 8){

        echo "<div class='cinemaCode'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(strlen($item) == 3){

        echo "<div class='cinemaListId'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(strlen($item) == 2){

        echo "<div class='cinemaListId'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(strlen($item) == 1){

        echo "<div class='cinemaListId'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $item) !== FALSE){;

        echo "<div class='cinemaTime'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(strpos($item, $findlink) !== false){

        echo "<div class='cinemaLink'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }elseif(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $item) !== FALSE){;

            echo "<div class='cinemaDate'>" . $item . "</div>";

    }else {

        echo "<div>" . $item . "</div>";

    }
}

echo "</ul>";

?>
```

This script however is outputting (with divs and classes of course, just don't want to add them all):

```
<li>The Smurfs 2 2D   30/08/2013   11:10</li>
<li>The Smurfs 2 2D   30/08/2013   13:20</li>
<li>The Smurfs 2 2D   31/08/2013   11:10</li>
<li>The Smurfs 2 2D   31/08/2013   13:20</li>
<li>Elysium   04/09/2013   15:45</li>
<li>Elysium   04/09/2013   21:00</li>
<li>Elysium   05/09/2013   15:45</li>
```

Is there any possible way to format it as follows:

```
<li>
The Smurfs 2 2D
30/08/2013 (today's date)
11:10   13:20
</li>

<li>
Elysium
04/09/2013 (today's date)
15:45   21:00
</li>
```

So just one film name, todays date and the times for that day (with classes ofcourse). Then onto the next film... etc.

I'm stuck and would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not just add `<br>` where you want to add a line break?

Comment: No as this will just add a new line with duplicated film name. I need to only output one film name and the times on that day.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the source layout or the front end html layout? If it's the source layout, have you tried replacing this:

```
echo "<div class='cinemaName'>" . $item . "</div>";
```

With this(?):

```
echo "<div class='cinemaName'>" . preg_replace( '   ', "\r\n", $item ) . "</div>";
```

Since it looks like there are 3 spaces between each segment of the `$item`, you can replace them with return shorthand `\r\n` (or just `\n` for some systems).

If it's the front end layout, just use the same method, but instead of `\r\n`, change it to `<br/>`.